# Moving XML tags to Table in Sql Server using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have a flat file with below data and want to move **Report** column tag values into respective columns in DB table,

```
SNO,EvID,Report
1,1E,<employee><name>John</name><location><Emp_Address>John Address</Emp_Address><city>John City</city></location><Compensation><Salary>2000</Salary><PF>100</PF></Compensation></employee>
2,2E,<employee><name>Jeff</name><location><Emp_Address>Jeff Address</Emp_Address><city>Jeff City</city></location><Compensation><Salary>4000</Salary><PF>400</PF></Compensation></employee>
```

I need to load report values alone into sql server table like below using SSIS,
[image]

Is it possible? I have tried to use XML task in SSIS, but not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: Have you managed to load any data into a table?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid No I couldn’t.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code -

```
drop table if exists #table1   -- Using Temp tables for example
Create table #table1 (SNO INT, EvID varchar(20), Report xml)

drop table if exists #table2
Create table #table2 (Name nvarchar(50), Emp_Address nvarchar(100), City nvarchar(50), 
Salary numeric(18,8), PF numeric(18,8))    -- Column taken as provided as sample XML data. Choose the data type according to your need.

BULK INSERT #table1 FROM 'C:\<FolderLocation>\<YourFileName>.<FileExtension>'
WITH (
    CODEPAGE = 'RAW', FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
)

select * from #table1

INSERT #table2
SELECT Report.value('(/employee/name)[1]', 'varchar(40)') AS Name,
    Report.value('(/employee/location/Emp_Address)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS Emp_Address,
    Report.value('(/employee/location/city)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS City,
    Report.value('(/employee/Compensation/Salary)[1]', 'numeric(18,8)') AS Salary,
    Report.value('(/employee/Compensation/PF)[1]', 'numeric(18,8)') AS PF
FROM #table1    -- Use your XML DOM structure to get the proper values

select * from #table2
```

Please Note, I have used XML data type to store your Report column value. `Value()` will work only if data type of the column will be XML.

Comment: is it possible to use above query in SSIS, if yes, let me know where I could use. Thanks

Comment: You can import your flat file directly into a table with the help of SSIS. For SELECT query, use the same OLEDB Source and OLEDB Destination to insert your data into destination table, and use SELECT query into OLEDB Source Object.